# An array of ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So, simple question that seems to be baffling me. I have a series of `ArrayList` because they need to be expandable. Now, I would like to be able to pull the nth object from each one with a simple for loop.

```
public ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<Integer> stamina = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public ArrayList<Integer> heart = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public ArrayList<Integer> intel = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public ArrayList<Integer> speed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I'll be adding/pulling information from these later in my code, so I would like it to be easily accessible via a single 2D array. With something like,

```
racerInfo[][] = { name, stamina, heart, intel, speed };
```

Then if I want information for, say, racer number 7

```
for ( int i=0; i<=racerInfo.length - 1; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(racerInfo[i][7]);
}
```

How would I go about setting up the `racerInfo` field? I can't seem to figure out the right setup. If you have any better suggestions for the rest I am completely open as I am still very new to this and just attempting to cobble something together that works.

Comment: Sorry, not answering the original question, but what you really want is a wrapper object e.g. `RacerInfo` instead of an array of lists. Also - a bit nit-picky - Try to create collections against their interfaces, not there implementations (`List list = new ArrayList()`)

Comment: Can't you create a racer pojo class with those attribute?

Comment: Sasvathan, I have no idea what a pojo class is. I've never heard of those before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach is a bit primitive, and you wouldn't have this problem if you had a better architecture.

Instead of having a bunch of lists of racer properties, you should create a racer class with the properties.

```
class Racer {
    private String name;
    private int stamina;
    ...
    public Racer(String name) {
       this.stamina = Math.random(...);
       ...
    }

    public function getStamina() {
       return this.stamina;
    }
}
```

Then you instantiate all your racers

```
Racer racer1 = new Racer("Alice");
```

and put them in a single list (or possibly a map) of racers:

```
List<Racer> racers = new ArrayList<Racer>();
racers.add(racer1);
```

or you could add them directly without first assigning them to a variable

```
racers.add(new Racer("Bob"));
```

Comment: A much better solution.

Comment: I think you should also add to your answer how to get Racer objects into the list eg `racers.add(new Racer(someString, someInt, ...))`

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding how this works. So, later on I'm going to use `Math.random()` to generate the stats for a racer. I know how I would add it to the `list` you've indicated, but how would I then pull the stats for display/implementation later? Like. I'm not sure what is storing the info or where it is being stored.

Comment: @MiuKujo I've added an example of how you do it. This is a very basic usage of plain Java objects. It's very fundamental and important that you understand how objects like these work, otherwise you won't get very far with Java.

Comment: @kba Unless I'm missing something, this sounds like I would have to create each racer manually, which is what I was trying to avoid by using lists.

Comment: @MiuKujo Creating these is no more manual than creating whatever you were doing before, I assure you. Why do you think creating these is more difficult?

Answer (score 0):

make racerInfo an arrayList of arrayLists, something like this

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> racerInfo = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(Arrays.asList(new ArrayList[]{name, stamina, heart, intel, speed}));
```